# PHP Header Location: URI determined by the script

Tags: php

A PHP script (for booking an event) exits to an HTML page for a ‘Thank you for your booking’ etc message with a usual:

```
header ("Location: http://www.thankyou.com/")
```

at the head of the script.

The script now also needs to exit to other HTML pages (‘Sorry – no spaces available’ etc) where the page URIs are only determined later in the script. It could issue more header function calls to replace the original header but this makes it vulnerable to accidentally inserted spaces.
This must be a common requirement; what please is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Define the header after all your logic is executed? The only rule for headers is there should be no *output* before they're defined.

Answer (score 0):

As far as no output is sent you can set headers (including the `Location` header for redirect) wherever you want in your script. There is no other better solution. Of course you would typically only do the operations you need to determine the destination of redirect and then redirect and exit script immediately, so redirects will be rather in the beginning of your script.

You should also place redirects in some predictable place, e.g. in your controller object or request validation function. It is not a good idea to have redirects scattered over many unrelated places, like inside many nested function calls etc.

If you have problems with accidental spaces, you should repair your scripts or use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) functions to buffer your accidental output and flush it only after all necessary headers has been sent.